# Node Crypto Encryption and decryption alogorithem

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I am looking for standard utility for supporting the encryption & decryption based on the below algorithm in node server side.
algorithm: aes-256-gcm
using the createCipheriv, createDecipheriv from nodejs crypto module.

Please suggest some working references

Comment: literally the first thing I found on google https://gist.github.com/rjz/15baffeab434b8125ca4d783f4116d81

Answer (score 0):

The utility need to build it from your side, and based on your needs below are the small code may help you to build the utility:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');


// This two value (ivValueEn , ivValueDe) should be same, to decode the text properly!
// you can generate any strong value and past it at the same place of you can have it from the config value.

  const ivValueEn = "c5949f09a7e67318888c5949f09a7e6c09ca51e602867318888c5949f09a7e6c09ca51e602867318888"; 
  const ivValueDe = "c5949f09a7e6c09ca51e602867318888c5949f09a7e6c09ca51e602867319ca51e602867318888";

// insert your key here, better to chose a strong key  
const keyValue = "c5949f09a7e6c09a7e6c09ca51e602867318888c5949f09a7e6c09ca51e602867318888";

// slicing are not required you can remove the slice(0,64) part & the console.log as well
  const alog = 'aes-256-gcm'
  const ivEn = ivValueEn.toString('hex').slice(0,64); console.log(ivEn);
  const ivDe = ivValueDe.toString('hex').slice(0,64); console.log(ivDe);

// The one that working with me correctly is to slicing the key to (32) characters. 
  const key = keyValue.slice(0,32);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(alog,key,ivEn);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv (alog,key,ivDe);
```